# Why doesn't setting backgroundColor have a visible effect on my custom UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

When I set the `backgroundColor` property of my Xib-instantiated subclass of `UIView`, the view's background color doesn't change but rather stays the color set in the Xib.

### Reproducing the issue

I have created a subclass of `UIView`, let's call it `MyView`, along with a Xib from which I instantiate it. Using Interface Builder, I have set the background color of the view in the Xib to blue.

I have added an instance of `MyView` as a subview of my app's main view. It appears blue, as expected.

I then added an outlet, `myView`, referencing that instance of `MyView`, and a button whose action attempts to change the view's background color like so:

```
@IBOutlet weak var debugView: MyView!

@IBAction func debug(_ sender: Any) {
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
```

I expected the background color of `myView` to change to green; instead, it stays blue like before.

### Observations

Strangely, if I check the background color of the view in the debugger, it seems that the property has been set to green, as expected, even though the change isn't visible:

```
(lldb) p debugView.backgroundColor == UIColor.blue
(Bool) $R1 = false
(lldb) p debugView.backgroundColor == UIColor.green
(Bool) $R2 = true
```

I have also tried forcing the view to redraw using `setNeedsDisplay()`, to no effect.

**Why doesn't my custom view's appearance reflect its `backgroundColor` property?**

Comment: `Debug View Hierarchy` might be helpful just to see if its not behind any other view.

Comment: @Kamran that's it! I followed the pattern of nesting the xib's "contentView" inside the subclassed view itself while deserializing, and so I need to set the contentView's property, not the view's property itself! I feel a little silly now

Comment: @Kamran If you'd care to put that as an answer in some form, I'll be happy to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably added a view from nib as subview to your customview in the swift file that is the reason on changing the backgroundcolor you would not see the changes. you need to change the background color of the subview of your debugview to see the color change.
For example:-

```
self.debugView.subviews.first?.backgroundColor = 
    self.debugView.subviews.first?.backgroundColor == UIColor.blue
        ? UIColor.black : UIColor.blue
```